# Rails where with greater than condition in join

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, join, where-clause

I have a hierarchy of four models:

```
Order

Job
  belongs_to :order

Task
  belongs_to :job
  belongs_to :agent

Agent
```

I'm trying to do a search for all tasks assigned to an agent for which the parent (grandparent?) Order has a due_date greater than than DateTime.now.

I can't seem to get the semantics right for this search.  The closest I've come is

```
agent.tasks.joins(job: :order)
           .where("task.job.order.due_date > ?", DateTime.now)
```

but that syntax is not correct. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you are passing strings into the `where` method, it requires that you write it as a valid SQL query. And in your case, the problem is how you reference the table name. While rails can parse a Hash structure and through the declaration of `belongs_to` and `has_many`, can understand what the following means

```
{ task: { job: { order: { due_date: Date.today } } } }
```

the database does not does not understand what to do with the following.

```
tasks.job.order.due_date
```

And it doesn't need to either. Since you have already specified how the tables are linked together by using `joins(job: :order)`, all you need to say in the `where` call is the following:

```
.where("orders.due_date > ?", DateTime.now)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating placeholder condition like:

```
agents.tasks.join(job: :order).where("taks.job.order.due_date > :due_date", {:due_date = DateTime.now})
```

But I don't know why are you using DateTime object there. Any particular reason?

I'd personally do it with

```
agents.tasks.join(job: :order).where("tasks.job.order.due_date > ?", Time.now.getutc)
```

Or if you don't use UTC, you can use corresponding TimeZone.

Also, do you have `has_many` clause in your `Order` class or `has_many :through`if you use different association?

Comment: The column value in Order is a DateTime, therefore doesn't work with a Time comparison, .e.g.,     Time.now.getutc != DateTime.now    and yes, there is a corresponding has_many clause in Order.